# What is the history of MSTest

Tags: nunit, mstest

A colleague of mine claims that Microsoft paid the developer of NUnit to develop MSTest. I have not been able to find any information that backs this claim up.

Is this true? What is the history of MSTest?

Comment: This probably belongs on stackexchange.

Comment: That must be some busy dude. After all, the developer of NUnit is also the developer of xUnit.NET! He *does* work at Microsoft, though, so I guess it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to [some random comment](http://Mtelligent.Com/journal/2008/7/1/automated-testing-with-nunit-mstest-mbunit-and-xunitnet.html) (scroll down to the very end) by some semi-anonymous random dude on an insignificant blog post somewhere on the intarwebz, this is not true.

And you know you can trust this info, since it came from the intarwebz!